# Wait until file completely read and then display the result in a rich textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task, async-await

I know that you cannot have GUI controls to work in a separate thread. On my form load I would like to read from a text file and then display the contents in a rich text box. I do the reading in a separate thread but since eventually I would like this text to appear on my Rich Textbox, my window still freezes and my loading spinner does not animate.

```
private async void PreviewFileForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.filePath);
    lblFileName.Text = fileName;
    richtxtboxPreview.Visible = false;
    string fileContents = await ReadFileAsync(this.filePath);
    richtxtboxPreview.Text = fileContents;
    richtxtboxPreview.Visible = true;
    spinnerLoadFile.Visible = false;
}

async Task<string> ReadFileAsync(string filePath)
{
    string s = String.Empty;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {           
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    });
    return s;
}
```

What can I do so that my loading bar spins to indicate waiting for the file to be read and then the rich text box show the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use async file I/O to do this. [Here's a Microsoft sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx)

So if you implement your async file reader like this (change the encoding to be the right kind for your text file; this code is copied verbatim from the Microsoft sample linked above):

```
private async Task<string> readFileAsync(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
        bufferSize : 4096, useAsync : true))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        int numRead;
        while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            // Use correct encoding here; maybe you need Encoding.UTF8
            string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
            sb.Append(text);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You should just be able to call it as you already are.

However, I've sometimes had weird things happen when doing stuff from the Load event.

In some cases, I fixed such problems by putting the code into a separate method and using BeingInvoke() to call it from the Load method, e.g.:

```
private void PreviewFileForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(doIt));
}

private async void doIt()
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.filePath);
    lblFileName.Text = fileName;
    richtxtboxPreview.Visible = false;
    string fileContents = await ReadFileAsync(this.filePath);
    richtxtboxPreview.Text = fileContents;
    richtxtboxPreview.Visible = true;
    spinnerLoadFile.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it still does not work. I used your approach. I also used BeginInvoke to no avail.

Comment: The problem is the line richtxtboxPreview.Text = fileContents; That means we are keeping the form control waiting for a result and this freezes the form. When I comment this line my loader spins and my form is responsive. So is there a way to keep everything else responsive and keep the loading of the rich text box in a separate thread?

Comment: @Pedram Is the text really so large that it takes a long time to insert into the control? Well, you can't do anything about it. Only the UI thread is allowed to assign to the `.Text` property.

Comment: I'm actually considering a worst case scenario when the file is very big and I would like my form to be responsive. In the future I'll have to do the same with datagrids. But as you say it is in fact tricky. If you cannot do it, then what is the point of putting a loading picture there? In 90% of the time the loading's result has to be displayed in a GUI control be it a text box, a grid or anything else. This is confusing to me.

Comment: @Pedram It should be very quick though. Remember that the UI won't be blocked while the file data is read - only when all the text has been read will the `richtxtboxPreview.Text = fileContents` execute, and that part should be very quick. It's the `await` that makes the UI continue to be responsive - it's not blocked at that point.